# React Native with Redux, access state from actions and stracture problems

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

i am building a simple application using react native and redux with react-native-router-flux.
I am facing a dead-end because of the approach i've chosen to solve the problem.
My app has 2 big datasets Products and Categories.
I have three screens

1. Home screen
2. Category screen
3. Product screen

When the app boots up , i am making two ajax requests , one to fetch the products and one to fetch the categories. When the requests resolve i am storing data in store

```
{ products: [...], categories: [...]}
```

The problem i'm facing is in the Categories Screen. From the categories screen the app renders a list of items and by clicking each of them i dispatch an action to execute Actions['Scene name'] , routing back to the same list component but this time providing the clicked category id.
So i'm presenting the whole category tree from parent to children using this technique.
The problem arises when there aren't any sub categories and i have to switch to another component and display products.

Every time an action is occurs i have to filter products array ( each item contains an array with product categories ids ) to find the category products

I feel i've dealt with the problem very wrong and i am asking for some guidance for how to store data in redux and navigate between Activities using the router.

A don't know if i've explained the problem enough. Bellow some snippets of my work so far

action.js

```
export const selectCategory = ({ title, id }) => {
    Actions.subCategoryList({ title, id });
    return ({
      type: SELECT_CATEGORY_PRODUCTS,
      payload: id
    });
  };
```

subCategoryList.js

```
render() {
            return (
                <FlatList
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF' }}
                    data={this.props.categories}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <CategoryListItem category={item} />}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                />
            );
        }

        const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        const categories = state.categories.filter((item) => {
            if (item.parentid === ownProps.id) return true;
            return false;
        });

        return {
            categories,
            category_products: state.products.selected_category_products
        };
    };
```

categoryListItem.js

```
categoryItemPressed() {
    this.props.selectCategory(this.props.category);
}

render() {
    const { category } = this.props;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={this.styles.buttonStyle} 
            onPress={() => this.categoryItemPressed()}
        >
            <View style={this.styles.containerStyle}>
                <Text style={this.styles.textStyle}>{category.title}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

export default connect(null, { selectCategory })(CategoryListItem);
```

Comment: Do you iterate throw your products array and map it to subCategoryList ? I think you should do so process there inatead of filter in each subCategoryList. Can you share the code for the parent component of subCategoryList ?

Comment: Subcategory list is called from my Router, passing as props the "sub-categories"  <Scene key="subCategoryList" component={SubCategoryList} title="Sub Category" />. That way i'm creating a recursiveness, my question is how to change the logic to can switch of it and display a products list.

Comment: I can suggest a little improvement, instead of filter each render, then map each item via flat list ( it mapped your products one by one to render them ), you can, in render, filter relevant items with conditional render:
`renderItem={ ({item}) => item.parentid === this.props.id ? <CategoryListItem category={item} /> : null }`

Comment: One more improvement can be done if you will store your data in HashTable like, there keys will be parentid and values will be items themself. In this approch, you will get much faster filter result, because you will be directly point to particular items instead of finding them.